# How to prevent tcpreplay from printing warning information?

Tags: pcap

I try to replay a large pcap file, while tcpreplay keep printing **"Warning: Packet #50579 has gone back in time".** 
That will affect the efficiency. It there a way to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

As of tcpreplay 3.4.4, you cannot completely silence this warning, but it's trivial to change the code to do so -- look at the definitions in src/common/err.h, and change the warnx() definition to become a no-op when debugging is disabled, similarly to dbg() and dbgx().

However, you should verify whether the output indeed affects packet throughput. I doubt it, particularly if it only affects a single packet.